# Laravel Transactions Not working when this condition happenes

Tags: php, laravel, try-catch

Let me start with my code

On my Controller file this is the code

```
namespace Something\Somewhere\Controller{
class Mobile extends Controller{
    public function saveMobilesIntoDb(Request $request,MediaManager $manager){
        $requestMobileData = $request->all();
        DB::beginTransaction();
        try{
            /*Do something*/
            ..
            ..
            $bigMediaArray = $manager->mobileImagesManager($media,$insertedMobile,$mediaSlug);
            ..
            ..
            DB::commit();
        }catch (\Exception $exception) {
            DB::rollback();
            dump($exception);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Notice I am using a service there, The service is nothing but a namespace to manage the code in the service class this what happening

```
namespace Something\Somewhere\Service{

class MediaManager{

    public function mobileImagesManager($media, $mobileId, $slug){
        //Do some stuff
        ///Create folder
        return array;
    }
}
```

Now the issue is when I get some error in the service and I resend the data then suppose the last id inserted into database was 5 and then the error came but didn't rolled back so it saved the new id with 7 . and I don't want this to happen. I know the rollback is not working when I am not in the scope but what I tried so far is

I wrapped the service function into try-catch and in the catch I used the DB::rollback() but it didn't helped.

Please let me know how do I solve it and rollback everything when I am not in the scope.

Thank you for you time

Comment: do you mean in the service function? no I didn't used the beginTransaction in that function

Comment: Depending on which database you're using, a rollback may not undo the advancement of an autoincrement id, leaving you with a "hole" in your sequence. It seems this is what you're describing, and it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @anasomush Yes I am using the DB::beginTransaction(); at the very top as you can see in the code.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I am using Mysql the the table is InnoDB, Innodb supports the transactions.as far as I know

Comment: Yes, but the incrementing of an autoincrement id is not part of that transaction, so if you roll back, you lose an id. You will likely find that your data did in fact get rolled back, you just have a hole in your id sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Alex said, due to Mysql official docs, the auto incremented ID will not rollback after transaction failure.

> In all lock modes (0, 1, and 2), if a
> transaction that generated
> auto-increment values rolls back,
> those auto-increment values are
> “lost.” Once a value is generated for
> an auto-increment column, it cannot be
> rolled back, whether or not the
> “INSERT-like” statement is completed,
> and whether or not the containing
> transaction is rolled back. Such lost
> values are not reused. Thus, there may
> be gaps in the values stored in an
> AUTO_INCREMENT column of a table.